# Get Rid of Borders Around Classes in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to get rid of the border lines that surround classes in PHPStorm?

[image]

Comment: Obviously off-topic, but in general it's regarded best-practice to have a single class per file. E.g. Thisismyclass1.php and Thisismyclass2.php. This way you'll also be able to implement an autoloader that will automatically load the class/file for you. More on autoloading: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no option to hide them (like method separators has) unfortunately.

But you can change/remove color for those lines, so they appear invisible: **Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Method separator color**

Answer (score 1):

*PHPStorm 9.0.2 update:*

It is now possible to hide those separator lines rather than merely modifying their color to camouflage them into invisibility.  You can hide the Method Separator lines as @LazyOne describes, and the right margin separator similarly:

**Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General > Right Margin**

[image: hide those fugly right margin separator lines]